# Remove duplicates of pairs in a list

Tags: list, function, haskell, tuples

I am familiar with the `nub` function on lists containing numbers, characters, or strings, but 
can someone explain to me how I can use the `nub` function from `Data.List` on a list of pairs?

Example:

```
[('a', 3),( 'b', 2),('a', 1),('b', 4)]
```

to

```
[('a', 3),('b', 2)]
```

As you can see, I want to remove all pairs where the key from the pair (key, value) is already in the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Prelude Data.List> nubBy (\(x,_) (x', _) -> x == x') [('a',1),('b',2),('b',3)]
[('a',1),('b',2)]
```

Comment: @sergeantSalty if you've found the answer useful, please accept it to indicate for future visitors of this page.

Comment: @Haleemur Ali 

Comment: That lambda can also be written as ``(==) `on` fst`` with `on` from `Data.Function`.

Comment: So I have integrated your way to remove the duplicates and it works very well. But i do not quite understand how the lambda expressions works here with the nubBy function. 
Please correct me if iam wrong.
nubBy gets a list as a Parameter and remove all duplicates from the list where the equality predicate returns true. But how exactly does the lambda expressions works here ? By the given example above can someone explain me which character will be taken for x and x' ?

Comment: @sergeantSalty the lambda type for `nubBy` is something like `a -> a -> Boolean`. That means it's a function with two parameters of the same type that returns True or False. I chose to represent two tuples, of the form `(x, _)` meaning a tuple with `x` and "anything." `x'` or "x prime" is just a convenience in Haskell - we could have written `y` instead of `x'`, it just means a different variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use 'seen' state variable to keep track of what elements have been already added. This works similar to the `nub` function, but is tweaked slightly to handle list of tuples. It accumulates results into a 'seen' list, and checks if the first element of each tuple exists in this list. If it found in 'seen', don't add it, otherwise add it to 'seen'.

Here is an example:

```
removeDuplicate :: (Eq a) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
removeDuplicate lst = go lst []
    where go [] seen = seen
          go (x:xs) seen 
              | any (\(a, _) -> a == fst x) seen = go xs seen
              | otherwise = go xs (seen ++ [x])
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> removeDuplicate [('a', 3),( 'b', 2),('a', 1),('b', 4)]
[('a',3),('b',2)]
```

This can also be written using [`foldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl):

```
removeDuplicate' = foldl (\seen x -> if any (\(a, _) -> a == fst x) seen
                                     then seen 
                                     else seen ++ [x]) []
```

One last over-kill approach is to sort the elements by the first element in each tuple beforehand with [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) from `Data.List`, then group them with [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy). Then simply take the first tuple from each group with [`map()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map), as shown here:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

removeDuplicate'' :: (Ord a) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
removeDuplicate'' xs = map head $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ sortBy (compare `on` fst) xs
```

**Note:** The answer given which suggested [`nubBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy) is the easiest way to do this, I just wanted to suggest alternative ways to do this.

Additionally, the third approach uses [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) from `Data.Function`, to make grouping and sorting easier.

Answer (score 2):

In the same vein as RoadRunner's answer, you could implement that `seen` as a [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Set.html) and even wrap it in the [`State`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) monad.

```
module Main where

-- mtl
import Control.Monad.State (State, get, put, evalState)
-- containers
import Data.Set            (Set, empty, insert, member)

removeDuplicates :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
removeDuplicates xs = evalState (go xs) (empty, [])
  where
  go [] = do
    (_, ys) <- get
    return $ reverse ys
  go (x:xs) = do
    (s, ys) <- get
    case member (fst x) s of
      True  -> go xs
      False -> do
        put $ (insert (fst x) s, x:ys)
        go xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let testData = [('a', 3),( 'b', 2),('a', 1),('b', 4)]
  print $ removeDuplicates testData
```

and again, just like RoadRunner's answer -- use `nubBy` to do this. This method is only interesting as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
λ:> import Data.List (nubBy)
λ:> import Data.Function (on)
λ:> nubBy ((==) `on` snd) [('a',1),('b',2),('b',3)]
[('a',1),('b',2),('b',3)]
```